# Ajax not working on wordpress inside embedded page

Tags: ajax, wordpress, iframe

link to bellow website is working perfectly fine,

https://soalsrv1.soaltech.com/jobs.nsf/xp_jobs_kupplin.xsp

but each time I use it in an embeded form like this:

```
<iframe src="https://soalsrv1.soaltech.com/jobs.nsf/xp_jobs_kupplin.xsp#" width="100%" height="600"> </iframe>
```

it doesn't work with iframe  but I need to add this as iframe to my website if any one knows the solution 'll be really Thankful :)

Comment: Why are you using an iframe inside your code? An iframe is used to embed on a website something of another website. (maybe some day will be deprecated) Is not a normal use inside your code. Explain it better please :)

Comment: so it means you have a better of using another website's code to my website right?

Comment: I have put your iframe code on my website as a test and it works. Some websites blocks iframes. Here is the test: https://iproject.cat/test.html

Comment: This is one of the first results of google: https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/ Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes iframes doesn't work on Wordpress, I've tried many times to put an Iframe of a simple Youtube video on an article page and it never appeared, I've read that Wordpress blocks them for security reasons but I think that with some payable plugin you can make it :/

Comment: This makes no sense.

Comment: I've spent an entire afternoon to try to render an iframe on an Article page, I've read that it could've been blocked by wordpress so I stopped trying...